# Trying to set BackColor equal to return value of a method in asp.net C# webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

On my .aspx page I have a label control where I'm trying to set the BackColor equal to the output of a method like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" BackColor='<%# getColor() %>'>hello</asp:Label>
```

In my code-behind I have the following:

```
public Color getColor()
{
    return System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

However, this isn't working. My label background doesn't change color based on the method output.

In my code-behind in the Page_Load section, if I say:

```
myLabel.BackColor = getColor();
```

this works.  So is it not working for me due to some kind of order of operations during page load? Or is my syntax wrong inside the control?

I realize this seems unnecessary as-is but I'm working towards more complex query-based logic functionality down the road. Just trying to get the most simple example working right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work you can use the `DataBind` method of your page like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DataBind();
    // or
    Page.DataBind();
    // or
    DataBind();
}
```

References:

- [Control.DataBind Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5e5992d(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [ASP.NET data binding overview](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307860/asp.net-data-binding-overview#1a)

  > After the particular data sources have been determined and set for the objects on the .aspx page, you must bind the data to these data sources. You can use the Page.DataBind or the Control.DataBind method to bind the data to the data sources.
  >   [...] 
  >   No data is rendered to the control until you explicitly call either the DataBind method of the Web server control or until you invoke the page-level Page.DataBind method. Typically, Page.DataBind (or DataBind) is called from the Page_Load event.

Comment: That's excellent, thank you. Would you mind explaining why that's needed? Does it have something to do with the timing of when the controls are rendered versus something or other?

Comment: You're welcome. `<%# %>`  is used for data binding. So you'll have to specify what to bind somewhere. I used this to bind some resources from resx files in the head section using `this.Header.DataBind()`.